# How to alloc a segment of memory using BIOS service?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I am tryng to alloc a free segment of memory using INT 12h BIOS service but I couldn't. How alloc free memory segments using INT 12h?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such BIOS service. Are you sure you didn't mean a DOS Interrupt service using Int 21h? (like Int [21h/AH=48h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2934.htm))?

Comment: If you only have the PC BIOS, not an OS, you *are* the OS and can use all the memory.  (Except for designated regions the BIOS owns).  At least all the lowmem where you know there won't be MMIO devices instead of DRAM.

Comment: I am trying to use a free segment of memory in MS-DOS with the INT 12h.

Comment: @BrunoGuimarãesSalvador " As I thought. This appears to be a DOS call question (not BIOS). I believe when you say Int 12h you mean int 21h. There is no Int 12h service (DOS or BIOS) that allocates memory. There are DOS Interrupts (Int 21h/ah=48h at the link I gave earlier) that can allocate memory. I would first verify that you do mean Int 12h. I am pretty sure you have reversed the numbers and mean Int 21h.

Comment: No! I don't reverse nothing! I want to find free segments of memory for my bootloader and in other case for a MS-DOS application. How to make those 2 things?

Comment: if you have a bootloader you are not running dos?  or you are running your bootloader on dos making this a dos question not a bios question?

Comment: @BrunoGuimarãesSalvador These two are entirely different questions.

Comment: Whether this is DOS program or BIOS `int 12h` doesn't allocate memory.Do you have a link to where you found that Int 12h would help you? In a bootloader you are free to use any available memory that is effectively between 0x0000:0x0600 (some people who don't care about old hardware use 0x0000:0x0500) and the top convention RAM at 0xa000:0x0000 (Minus the sise of the EBDA). In a bootloader you manage your own memory. In DOS you can't write anywhere in memory you want. You ask DOS to allocate memory for you. [`21h/AH=48h`] is a method in DOS to do just that: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2934.htm

Answer (score 3):

> INT 12h

This interrupt is tells you how much memory the computer has below the address `0A0000h`.

The interrupt will return the number of kilobytes in `AX`. This means that you multiply the value of `AX` with `0x400` to get the number of bytes of memory; or you multiply it with `0x40` to get the number of segments.

Example: If the interrupt returns `AX=0x1E0`, the RAM ends at address`0x7800:0` or `0x7000:0x8000` (both segmented addresses represent the linear address `0x78000`).

> I want to find free segments of memory for my bootloader ...

The BIOS does not do memory management. The OS (e.g. MS-DOS) does this!

When your boot loader is in memory, no OS is loaded yet.

This means that you have to do the memory management yourself: The entire RAM of the computer is "owned" by your boot loader!

The easiest way is to use fixed addresses in your boot loader. Because the entire RAM is "owned" by the boot loader, you can decide that some kind of data is always stored at the address 0x2000:0. You don't have to do some kind of allocation.

If you actually require dynamic memory allocation, you'll have to write a function that allocates the memory by storing information about which part of the memory is not "allocated", yet.

Especially if you require a function for freeing memory, this is quite tricky!

> ... and in other case for a MS-DOS application.

In this case the memory management is performed by MS-DOS, not by the BIOS.

You'll have to call MS-DOS functions (and not BIOS functions) to perform memory management.

> ... alloc a free segment of memory using INT 12h BIOS service ...

By the way:

A boot loader could modify `int 12h` to return a smaller value in the `ax` register. Doing so, it would be possible to store data in the RAM (for example for a modified BIOS interrupt service routine) which is not overwritten by the OS.

However, this will only work if the OS checks the RAM size using `int 12h`. If the OS assumes that the RAM size is fixed to 640 kilobytes or if it uses one of the newer `int 15h` RAM size services, this will not work.

Comment: Int 12h returns the amount of available memory minus the EBDA if one is sitting just below 0a000:0x0000 (often it is 1k and DOS reports 639).It should be noted that calling `Int 12h` in DOS in some circumstances can yield a segment higher than 640. THis can occur if you are using an expanded memory manager that moves the EBDA (on hardware that supports it) from just under video ram to somewhere in the low part of conventional memory.

Comment: If you have a memory manager that allows you to use video ram as program memory then the memory manager can move the EBDA (on supported hardware) and hook onto Int 12h and lie and tell DOS that there is 704k. In some environments that are headless (no video) that ram size can be higher. In essence the the number reported by Int 12h is usually the largest contiguous chunk of usable memory available under 1MiB and it may not be the same value reported by the BIOS at power on if some driver has intercepted Int 12h to probide a new value to DOS.